# Flattr a URL via API

Tags: flattr

I am an Instapaper user and am just trying to write a script that fetches my "liked"-folders RSS-Feed, takes the link of the webpage and flattrs it.

So far, I am stuck at "committing" the flattr - is there any API, etc. for that task or must a flattr always be done 'by hand'?

Thanks,
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an API which is documented at http://developers.flattr.net/. You can either flattr the URL of the webpage or the flattr ID (in case you know it). You will need an OAuth2 access token to do so, but the documentation explains how you can obtain it.

Comment: Could you give me a direct link to that API? (sry, just don't find it ;))

Comment: To flattr a thing? Sure: http://developers.flattr.net/api/resources/flattrs/#flattr-a-thing and http://developers.flattr.net/api/resources/flattrs/#flattr-a-url